# Using a pipe character | with child_process spawn

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process

I'm running nodejs on a raspberry pi and I want to run a child process to spawn a webcam stream.

Outside of node my command is:

```
raspivid -n -mm matrix -w 320 -h 240 -fps 18 -g 100 -t 0 -b 5000000 -o - | ffmpeg -y -f h264 -i - -c:v copy -map 0:0 -f flv -rtmp_buffer 100 -rtmp_live live "rtmp://example.com/big/test"
```

With `child_process` I have to break each argument up

```
var args = ["-n", "-mm", "matrix", "-w", "320", "-h", "240", "-fps", "18", "-g", "100", "-t", "0", "-b", "5000000", "-o", "-", "|", "ffmpeg", "-y", "-f", "h264", "-i", "-", "-c:v", "copy", "-map", "0:0", "-f", "flv", "-rtmp_buffer", "100", "-rtmp_live", "live", "rtmp://example.com/big/test"];
```

```
camera.proc = child.spawn('raspivid', args);
```

However it chokes on the `|` character:

```
error, exit code 64
Invalid command line option (|)
```

How do I use this pipe character as an argument?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has been answered in another question: [Using two commands (using pipe |) with spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273253/using-two-commands-using-pipe-with-spawn/39482486#39482486)

In summary, with `child.spawn` everything in `args` should be an argument of your 'raspivid' command. In your case, the pipe and everything after it are actually arguments for `sh`.

A workaround is to call `child.spawn('sh', args)` where args is:

```
 var args = ['-c', <the entire command you want to run as a string>];
```