# Using two commands (using pipe |) with spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn, pdftotext, unoconv

I'm converting a doc to a pdf (unoconv) in memory and printing (pdftotext) in the terminal with:

```
unoconv -f pdf --stdout sample.doc | pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 - out.txt
```

Is working. Now i want use this command with `child_process.spawn`:

```
let filePath = "...",
process = child_process.spawn("unoconv", [
  "-f",
  "pdf",
  "--stdout",
  filePath,
  "|",
  "pdftotext",
  "-layout",
  "-enc",
  "UTF-8",
  "-",
  "-"
]);
```

In this case, only the first command (before the |) is working. Is i possible to do what i'm trying?

Thanks.

UPDATE-

Result of: `sh -c- ....`

```
bash-3.2$ sh -c- unoconv -f pdf --stdout /Users/fatimaalves/DEV/xx/_input/sample.doc | pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 - -
sh: --: invalid option
Usage:  sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
    sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --protected
    --rcfile
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
    --wordexp
Shell options:
    -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option      (invocation only)
    -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Comment: It's not `sh -c-`. It's `sh -c`.

Answer (score 16):

Everything starting with the pipe is not an argument to `unoconv`. It is processed by the shell, not by `unoconv`. So you can't pass it as part of the argument array in `unoconv`.

There are a number of ways around this, depending on your needs. If you know you will be running on UNIX-like operating systems only, you can pass your command as an argument to `sh`:

```
process = child_process.spawn('sh', ['-c', 'unoconv -f pdf --stdout sample.doc | pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 - out.txt']);
```

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to use the `sh` command as explained above, you must create multiple child_process.spawn instances and then pipe them into each other like so:

```
const getModule = spawn('curl', [url, '-ks']);
const unTar = spawn('tar', ['-xvz', '-C', fileName, '--strip-components', 1]);
getModule.stdout.pipe(unTar.stdin);
```

The above code theoretically will retrieve a tar from `url`, and unpack into a directory `fileName`

Comment: This is the most cross-environment way to do this, and it doesn't introduce an extra layer of shells like the `sh -c ...` solutions do.