# Executing NodeJS Program with Sudo then use spawn without sudo

Tags: node.js, sudo

The question is related to [Running command from Node.js with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785436/running-command-from-node-js-with-sudo/)
(No working answer have been ever given).

A program is currently executed that way:
sudo node xx.js
This can't be changed, need the 80 port.

Now, I'm trying to use spawn and execute something without sudo, I've attempted to use uid: and guid:, however it doesn't actually work, it's still using sudo permissions.

How can I use spawn (or exec) - or even a Worker without sudo?

`spawn(path,[], { uid: 1000, gid: 1000});` => This does not work (it should do a spawn with the right uid, but it doesnt), 1000 is the right one, checked by using id in terminal (root is 0, my user is 1000)

Thank you

Comment: Without "sudo" you mean, the child process should not be have root premissions/should run under a "nobody" user? Add a minimal working example.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm having a hard time figuring out a working example except putting the uid: guid: as I did in my mini sample.

You said it right, the child process (or even Worker could be okay) should not have root permissions. It should run under the uid/guid that I've specified.

Comment: Try spawning the `su` command then tell `su` to execute your command.

Comment: But su would simply upgrade my privileges no? I want to downgrade my privileges